# Open up link in new window maximised

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to open up a new window but in maximised format (spec. in IE7 and IE6)? Javascript methods are OK in this instance too.

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't do this! A lot of people, me included, really _hate_ when the site being loaded is doing things to the browser window. I get an instant suspicioun that the site in question is trying to divert my attention while it drops malicious code in the background. Just a friendly hint that you're welcome to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Use

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open)

and use the

fullscreen

option.

But before doing that read this also

[Note on fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open#Note_on_fullscreen)

***Example***

```
var WindowObjectReference;

function openRequestedPopup()
{
  WindowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImageFile.png",
                  "DescriptiveWindowName",
                  "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,fullscreen=yes");
}
```